# What is the Windows RT / Windows Store App answer to App.config?

Tags: windows-8, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps

What is the best way to go about reading and writing simple configuration data like we used to use App.config and Web.config `<appsettings />` available through `ConfigurationManager` before, for use within your Windows 8 / Windows RT / Windows Store / Windows Modern UI App?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

**LocalSettings**

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.storage.applicationdata.localsettings

OR

**RoamingSettings**

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.storage.applicationdata.roamingsettings.aspx

The main difference is that RoamingSettings will be saved to the cloud and thus, can be transferred across different devices for the same user profile. LocalSettings is device-specific.

Comment: Akinwale, I have received three very good answers, but given this to you to boost your rep, thanks for the response!

Answer (score 9):

Metro apps don't have exact equivalent of app.config/web.config.

Instead you should use [package.appxmanifest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh464929.aspx#package_manifest) to configure windows store specific values.

For local settings you should use [ApplicationData](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh700361.aspx) api.

If you want to configure application after it is deployed you could simply load remote xml or json file at application start up.

Comment: Thanks Denis, you and Akinwale were very close on answers.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the technical answers above its important to understand why there is no config file for these apps.

WinRT/Windows store apps are client applications so unlike your ASP.NET applications that run on the server and require admin configuration changes, end users are not expected to tinker with these changes (SQL connection, timeouts, appSettings you name it) hence there is no need for such a config file for these apps,

Hope it makes sense

Comment: .config files were not exclusive to web applications, so I have no idea what your answer is in reference to.

Answer (score 0):

You can find a sample to mimic app.config in Windows Store apps based on XML files [here](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Mimic-appconfig-in-Windows-dffb8160)

Hth

Stefan

Comment: Note that [link-only answers](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/link-only-answers/info) are discouraged, SO answers should be the end-point of a search for a solution (vs. yet another stopover of references, which  tend to get stale over time). Please consider adding a stand-alone synopsis here, keeping the link as a reference.