# How to store configuration in Window8 RT Application?

Tags: wcf, xaml, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps

I need to connect Win8 app to WCF service. The WCF client is created using [Add Service Reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh556233.aspx).

The requirement is to change the End point URL at runtime. Win 8 does not have [app.config](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12869139/what-is-the-windows-rt-windows-store-app-answer-to-app-config) and instead use [Application Data](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br241587.aspx) settings.

The problem is that App needs the URL at the startup. If URL is invalid, or cannot be reached, the app is terminated.

The question is, How to manage scenarios, where configuration settings are required for app startup, and to be set up at runtime?

Answer (score 1):

When you create an instance of the client, before you start using it you can change the address for the service by accessing the `Endpoint` property of the client. Something like the code below.

```
var client = new ServiceReference1.ServiceClient();
client.Endpoint.Address = new EndpointAddress(yourNewUri);
```

Comment: The newURI will come from local/roaming settings. How to set/reset these at runtime? (I donot want to use settings charm, instead just plain csv/xml file somewhere at disk)

Comment: Just read from / write to a file in disk prior to / after using it.