# Save configuration data in WinRT metro apps

Tags: c#, windows-8, windows-runtime, winrt-xaml

In web or desktop application (WinForms, WPF,ASP.NET), the app.config or web.config is a potential place to put things like connection strings or uri's used within the app. This allows the end user to change these settings, application wide, without having to have a developer rebuild and redeploy.

How to do this is WinRT apps?

I found few links like save in xml file and deployed with package like 
[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19994632/what-is-the-equivalent-of-an-app-config-in-a-winrt-app) and [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pasen/archive/2012/02/04/developing-windows-8-app-accessing-configuration-files-deployed-as-part-of-deployment.aspx). But I am unable to understood how it works for all users who are using the app. Suppose I save a rest api url in xml file and create an app package and deployed on store. Now suppose if I have to change the url then how will it works and how to make it dynamic? Where I have to change the configuration so that all users have the latest url's.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the Windows RT / Windows Store App answer to App.config?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12869139/what-is-the-windows-rt-windows-store-app-answer-to-app-config)

Comment: I hope you found the answer for that Question

Answer (score 1):

I use `LocalState` folder to save the `config.ini` file to store all the configurations used in app. This directory exists within AppPackage. i.e.

`C:\Users\{User}\AppData\Local\Packages\{AppPackage}\LocalState\`

You can place your config file here, and can access it this way:

```
StorageFile configFile = await ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.GetFileAsync("Config.ini");
IList<string> configs = await FileIO.ReadLinesAsync(configFile);
```

This way one can change configuration(s) without having to create AppPackage, again.

Comment: Suppose after deployment I have to edit it how do I do that?

Comment: Open `C:\Users\{User}\AppData\Local\Packages\{AppPackage}\LocalState` directory, make changes to `config.ini` file. Save it, and restart your app.

Comment: Suppose I published the app on store now I have to change the config that hows its possible?

Comment: Then you need to host this file to server, download the file to `LocalState` and use it like mentioned above.

Comment: This is not the good approach because every time user has to download it

Comment: I'm not saying the user has to download the file. Downloading of `config` file should be coded in app.

Answer (score 0):

WinRT apps are installed per user on the computer.

So each user will need to make the change.

Note that you will need to provide a ui for them to use as well.

If you use some of the newer settings options in winRT you can have the settings sync to all devices for the user.

For more info see 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/mt299098.aspx

Comment: Thanks but can u provide a small example for this ?

Comment: This should help https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/ApplicationData